# Laravel: SoftDeletes doesnt work when I add $appends field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model with softdeletes, if I add A appends field my sofdeletes implementation doesnt work, somebody knows what is happend?

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Users extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $appends = ['assigned'];

    protected $fillable = ['category_id'];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->assigned = false;
    }

    public function setAssignedAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['assigned'] = $value;
    }

    public function getAssignedAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a `assigned` field in your table?

Comment: no, it is a append field, this is the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your appends field.  It's your constructor not calling the parent constructor which is what boots your soft deletes trait.  Add a `parent::__construct()` to your constructor.  It should match the signature of the parent as well so it should be:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->assigned = false;

    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You misread the documentation, your accessor doesn't have the right name:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Users extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $appends = ['assigned'];

    protected $fillable = ['category_id'];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->assigned = false;
    }

    public function setIsAssignedAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['assigned'] = $value;
    }

    public function getIsAssignedAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

You need the `Is` even thought it is not part of the variable name.